# Javascript style.display not staying changed in VS2012

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2012

I just started using Visual Studio 2012 and for some reason jQuery and Javascript seem to be acting funny. I can not get jQuery toggle() to work.  Even something as basic as 
    ('#displayNoneDiv').style.display = 'block';
Shows for a second, then disappears. Does anyone know what that is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your element shows for a moment then disappears, there is likely additional code which  executes after the "block" assignment.

Using a javascript debugger, set a breakpoint at the *('#displayNoneDiv').style.display = 'block'* line and step through.  Monitor the css properties of the *displayNoneDiv* element during each line of execution to determine what is causing the element to become hidden.

Comment: Great tip - eventually I found that it was doing a postback because the asp:button.  I changed to an input and that fixed it for now.